# Cordova outgoing calls number plugin

Tags: cordova, plugins

I'm try to create a cordova plugin for intercept outgoing call and get the number called.

But when i run the app it return me a error, it go in errorCallback function.

Java code:

```
public class OutgoingCall extends CordovaPlugin {
    private Context context;
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext 
callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        Context ctx = this.context;
        String number = args.getString(0);
        return true;
    }
}
class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private CallbackContext callbackContext;
    public void setCallbackContext(CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        this.callbackContext = callbackContext;
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (state == null) {
            String phoneNumber =intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.e("Number=", phoneNumber);
            JSONObject jso = new JSONObject();
            try {
                jso.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                phoneNumber = "Errore 2!";
            }
            PluginResult result = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK,phoneNumber);
            result.setKeepCallback(true);
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(result);
        }
    }
}
```

JS code:

```
var OutgoingCall = {
    onReceive: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        errorCallback = errorCallback || this.errorCallback;
        cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'OutgoingCall','onReceive', []);
    },

    errorCallback: function() {
        console.log("WARNING: OutgoingCall errorCallback not implemented");
    }
};

module.exports = OutgoingCall;
```

I have added in plugin.xml

```
<config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
            <feature name="OutgoingCall">
                <param name="android-package"value="org.outgoingcall.cool.OutgoingCall" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
            <uses-permissionandroid:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
            <receiver android:name=".OutgoingCallReciver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </config-file>
```

I use plugin in onDeviceReady function but the plugin go in errorCallback function.

Please help me, i'm desperate!

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Use one more permission in your Android Manifest file and also I see that, there are syntax error in your plugin.xml
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

Comment: Then i change this 

    <uses permission 
  
  android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
?